# Redis - possible to view hit/miss of individual keys?

Tags: redis

Is it possible to obtain the hit/miss counts of individual keys in redis? While it is possible to use the `INFO` command in `redis-cli` to obtain the `keyspace_hits` and `keyspace_misses`, they are too generic to be useful to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not possible, redis source code:

```
server.stat_keyspace_misses++;
```

But you can write your own wrapper for your redis client.

Comment: Thanks amenzhinsky. For the curious, this line of code is in the `lookupKeyRead` function in `src/db.c`. Specifically, I am basing it on commit `55f90b11c9`.